# dependency between list elements

Tags: java, list

I have 4 services. Each one depend on someone else e.g if service A start then can B and C, if B starts then can  D start. if A->B and C, if B-> D. I have manage to create their start() and stop() method but i just don't know how to make dependence between them. I was thinking about sending to ChechRequirements class service that he has to run and list of service that that service is depending on and if that list equal to the currently running list he can start like others before that service. Is this a good idea or you have another one?

Thank you so much

Comment: What should happen when a thread tries to start while its dependent threads didn't start yet?

Comment: he just shouldn't start

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to rely on an approved framework such as OSGi (and his Apache Felix implementation).

If you want for any reason stay on your own framework, I suggest you to design and set up a lifecyle management based on those steps :

1. Stopped : Service is present
2. Inactive : Service is initialized but dependancies are not available
3. Ready : All conditions for run are valid (such as dependancies)
4. Started : Service can handle requests

Then, when a starting a service which depends on another one, you must level up the state of the dependancy. And when stopping a dependancy you must down the state of the dependant services.